# Printing an image rotated in Java adds artifacts

Tags: java, image, printing, awt

I'm trying to print a simple image in Java with a small rotation transform.  When the image is printed, there are artifacts at the image borders that are not in the original image, so the image comes out with these black lines at the borders.

Has anybody seen this before?

To replicate, run the following code:

```
package test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.File;

import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Destination;

public class TestPrintBug implements Printable
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        try
        {
            PrintService[] services = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();
            for (int index = 0; index < services.length; index++) 
            {
                if (services[index].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Microsoft XPS Document Writer"))
                {
                    PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
                    HashPrintRequestAttributeSet attributes = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
                    attributes.add(new Destination(new File("c:/test.xps").toURI()));
                    pjob.setPrintable(new TestPrintBug(), new PageFormat());
                    pjob.setPrintService(services[index]);
                    pjob.print(attributes);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Throwable t)
        {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException 
    {
        if (pageIndex == 0)
        {
            try
            {
                int width = (int)(8.5 * 72);
                int height = 1 * 72;

                BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                Graphics2D biG = bi.createGraphics();
                biG.setColor(Color.yellow);
                biG.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

                Graphics2D g2Print = (Graphics2D)graphics;
                g2Print.transform(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(-0.02));
                g2Print.drawImage(bi, 0, 144, null);

                return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
            }
            catch(Throwable t)
            {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> When the image is printed, there are artifacts at the image borders
>   that are not in the original image, so the image comes out with these
>   black lines at the borders.

I see that you are rotating the image with only -0.02 radians which is roughly -1.15 degrees. This is a very small angle for an image that is so small (612 X 72 pixels). The smallest unit of an image is a pixel which can be only rotated by 90 degrees or multiples of 90 degrees. The libraries address this issue by rotating only some pixels by 90 degrees. But this algorithm becomes less effective when the rotation angle and image pixel size both are small - as in your case. That's the reason you are seeing those black borders. This is obviously not a bug in the `AWT` libraries.  You might want to increase the rotation angle if allowed or use high resolution images. Also, if you rotate a non-square image by an angle not in multiple of 90 degrees, you need to make sure you the rotated image fits in the original viewport. If it doesn't, you have to write extra code to paint the area of the image falling out of the viewport.

P.S. you also should dispose the resources such as `Graphics2D` and `BufferedImage` after use to avoid memory leak. E.g. call `g2Print.dispose();` in the end.

Comment: There is no reason why painting an image with rotation should ever introduce artifacts.  Doing so essentially corrupts the output and would therefore makes rotation unusable.  This is a solved problem in image processing.  We've tested this with other applications and programming frameworks and have never seen this happens.  Additionally, this only happens in Java when printing:  When painting to the screen, or to another image, there is no issue.

Comment: We believe that this is definitely a bug in AWT / Swing.  We've reported the bug to Java but in the meantime we were hoping someone has run into this and found a workaround.